# Wait for changes to be applied in AngularJS / general javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, browser, render

I'm using AngularJS for an application and encountered a certain problem with pushing of changes to the view.

**Use case**

When I do major updates to the view/data (xhr requests, restoring state and the lot), I inidicate that with a loader gif to the user. I use a flag which is bound to the img tag (using ngClass), so the loader gif is displayed when the flag is set. The flag is also used as a lock (not in a thread safe way, but good enough for the task at hand). I acquire the lock (set the flag) on starting a process and release it after the last promise ($q) of all xhr calls is resolved.

**Issue**

When I restore data using the HTML5 history API and load data from the server (on reload, forward or backwards), the view can take a noticeable time to reflect the changes made to the model. As I only rely on the promises of the http request, my loader gif is hidden before the view is (visibly) updated. Is there a way to detect when the changes are visible to the user instead of watching model changes? This is probably no longer an Angular issue but a general JS problem.

**Time line**

(1) Setting flag ->

(2) Executing xhr/model changes ->

(3) Releasing lock ->

(4) AngularJS finished applying ->

(5) Changes are visible

The issue mostly lies between steps 4 and 5 (also 3 and 4, but this is actually not really noticeable).

**Example**

As a user I can clearly see the table rows being generated, but the table cells are still empty. After some dozens milliseconds, the values appear. I'm not sure whether that's default Angular behavior or my browser having troubles rendering the changes to the HTML quick enough.

**My thoughts**

I guess the issue is intertwined with the way browsers update the viewport. I didn't really dig into that yet, but it seems to me that Angular has actually applied the changes but they're not yet rendered by the browser. Using a directive watching the main data table for the $last flag, I can detect a considerable delay between ng-repeat finishing and the view being rendered visibly. It might be that this is getting way too much into the specifics of a browser, but maybe somebody else has some thoughts on that to share :)

Comment: Post some code please. Maybe you need to run $scope.$apply

Comment: There's no issue with AngularJS applying the changes of the model. All data is correctly represented in the view at the end. The problem lies in the noticeable delay between AngularJS finishing applying and the browser effectively rendering the new HTML.
I've included a time line and an example to clarify.

Comment: Just to follow up my thoughts about there being a performance problem with the browser:
After (finally) getting the update of Firefox which seems to get rid of the FireBug bug, I can confirm that this bug at least increased the gravity of the delay. I still need to use the tricks mentioned by HarishR and package, but it's definitely better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have directive with lowest priority... e.g. -1 and use that directive to show or hide the spinner/gif element

as the directive with the lowest priority, this will be executed last in the view updates. so the show-spinner can be false at part of this directive, hence spinner would hide only after all the changes are rendered...

[PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/6hW80o?p=preview)

Comment: As far as I know, the priority sorts directives **on single element**, not all directives currently in the DOM. Given the loader gif is on element which is above table element with data in the DOM, will priority have any effects in this case?

Comment: @package: as far as my understanding its in the DOM, thats how the ng-cloak directive works... but confirmting this with a plunk

Comment: @package: added plunker link

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. I was refering to the docs: `When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied.`, but that's apparently not true.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit hackish, but I had a situation where external lib would have to attach event listeners to elements generated by `ngRepeat`. Obviously the elements wheren't there yet when the model watcher fired, so what I did was a custom directive on `ngRepeat` element that would watch `ngRepeat`'s `$last` property and then would `$evalAsync` required callback. Here's the idea:

```
.directive('onRepeatFinish', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      if (scope.$last === true) {
        scope.$evalAsync(attributes.onRepeatFinish);
      }
    }
  };
})
```

With that in mind, you could hide loader image not when the lock is released, but when some event, let's say `renderComplete`, is sent by this directive.

template:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in data" on-repeat-finish="$emit('renderComplete')"></div>
```

handler in $rootScope:

```
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('renderComplete', function(){
    $rootScope.showLoader = false;
  })
})
```